# Android LibSpeechKit file not opened

Tags: android, nexus-5

My nexus 5 keeps posting

```
09-08 10:12:29.523    6214-6397/? E/LibSpeechKit﹕ -1595581056 [909215 ms] size_t Util::WavOutputStream::write(const void*, size_t): file not opened
```

to the tracestack. It occurs every 140 ms. I'm checking running apps and services but nothing new apart from my usual apps. It started 2 days ago. Anyone else having this problem? It also blocks my "Ok google" command and speech recognition.